# Querying mongoDB document based on Array element

Tags: arrays, mongodb, node-mongodb-native, database

[image]

This is one user's notes. I want to query and get only the notes of this use with "activeFlag:1". My query object code is

```
findAccountObj = 
{ _id: objectID(req.body.accountId),
 ownerId: req.body.userId,
 bookId: req.body.bookId,
"notes.activeFlag": 1 };
```

But this query returns all the notes, including the ones with "activeFlag:0".
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on v2.2, use elementmatch operator. v3.2 and above allow aggregation and filter to return a subset of a document.

here is an example [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)